# How to get previous task local variables of a running process instance in activiti

Tags: spring-boot, activiti

I am developing a spring boot application with activiti as the workflow engine. The activiti-spring-boot-starter dependency version is 7.1.0.M6 and spring-boot-starter-parent version is 2.6.7.

I have defined a BPMN 2.0 diagram using activiti-modelling-app and I am now starting the process instance. After completing a task, I want to access its task local variables when processing the next task. I am unable to figure out the api for it.

I tried using the `historyService` as below but with no luck. I get the result list as empty everytime with different apis (`finished()`, `unfinished()` etc)

```java
HistoricTaskInstance acceptMobile = historyService.createHistoricTaskInstanceQuery()
                .processInstanceId(processInstanceId)
                .taskName("my-task1")
                .singleResult();
```

Can someone guide me on what could be the right api to use to get the local variables of a previously completed task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to transfer variables between tasks is to use execution variables with `DelegateExecution`

execution variables are specific pointers to where the process is active, for more information, see [apiVariables](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#apiVariables)

Let say you have `Task-A` and `Task-B` with different listeners

here's how to use execution variable from `Task-A` to `Task-B`:

```java
@Component("TaskListenerA")
public class TaskListenerA implements TaskListener {

    @Override
    public void notify(DelegateTask task) {
         DelegateExecution execution = task.getExecution();
         if("complete".equals(task.getEventName()) {
             String myTaskVar = (String) task.getVariable("taskAvariable")
             execution.setVariable("exeVariable", myTaskVar);
         }
    }
}
```

```java
@Component("TaskListenerB")
public class TaskListenerB implements TaskListener {

    @Override
    public void notify(DelegateTask task) {
         DelegateExecution execution = task.getExecution();
         String myVariable = execution.get("exeVariable");
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case I am completing Task-A in a custom rest api implementation. How do I get the DelegateExecution instance from taskService?

Comment: You cannot get  `DelegateExecution` from `taskService` , you can set task variable with `taskService.setVariable("myvariable","value from Task A")`  after  have to use  `TaskListener` for the event `complete` and add the local variable to executions. I'll edit the code to show you how to make sure you are on complete event.


Note that you can get variable from execution scope if available with `taskService.getVariables(taskId) ` for your `task-B` see [TaskService](https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/TaskService.html#getVariables-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Does ```taskService.setVariable("myvariable","value from Task A")``` set the variable as a task local variable and ```execution.setVariable("exeVariable", myTaskVar);``` as a process variable? Logically get the previously completed tasks from the history service and then fetching its variables sounds like a ideal approach and putting the variable first through the ```taskService``` and then fetching it from the ```listener``` looks like a workaround. 

Also ```taskService.getVariables(taskId)``` doesn't work for already completed tasks right? It works only for only the active task.

Comment: Yes `task.setVariable` is to set local task variable and `execution.setVariable` for process variable. using `Listeners` to handle variables is not a workaround, it's the best practice, especially if you build advanced and complexes workflow, easier to maintain, 

Plus, you don't have choice if you want to use `exclusiveGateway`, the conditions are based on process variable.

you can also use `Javascript` listener in your `bpmn` to set `execution variable` , I suggest you this [tutorial](https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html)

Comment: `historyService` is not optimized for runtime or to handle variables, see [HistoryService](https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/HistoryService.html)